# Get Previous and Next Sunday from another time zone

Tags: php, date, timezone

I need a script that will return the next sunday and previous saturday from the date . I know how i can return that value from the current date

```
$saturday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime( "next saturday" ));

$sunday = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("previous sunday"));
```

But i have user and his timezone is different say 'Europe/Zurich'(different timezones will be used)

I need to get his previous sunday's date and next saturday.

I wrote a script like this . But i am not sure about the accuracy of the  script since it is timezone related task.Please help  me to fix this.

```
   $actual_server_time = new DateTime;
   $actual_server_time->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Zurich'));    
   $converted_server_date_time = $actual_server_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
   $actual_server_time->modify('last Sunday');
   $actual_server_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but next Saturday and previous Sunday will be equal for all time zones.. If it is the time (hour and minute) you are worrying about, then you can convert the timestamps to correct timezone.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the timezone in  strtotime:

```
<?php strtotime("previous sunday GMT+1");
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/04abfb591061aab66815a3c76868b1ef34ef1005)